# Вывод информации об успешной регистрации

Tags: всплывающее-окно, php, регистрация, javascript

Доброго всем дня!
Пишу уже от безысходности...)
В общем вот что имеется на данный момент.

1) Форма регистрации, которая проходит в всплывающем окне с затемнением(как задумывалось) - там все работает. Сделано посредством css.
2) После регистрации планируется вывести информацию в новом всплывающем окне. Однако! Тут у меня начинаются проблемы с кодом. И вот в чем они состоят.

а) Код регистрации:

```
    <?php
    require_once "functions.php";

    /* Получаем и обрабатываем данные */
    $login = escape($_POST['login']);
    if (strlen($login) == 0) exit;
    $password = escape($_POST['password']);
    if (strlen($password) == 0) exit;
    $mail = escape($_POST['mail']);
    if (strlen($mail) == 0) exit;
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db('auth_reg');
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `mail`='{$mail}'";
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)!=0)
{
    echo '<div style="width: 370px;
 height:180px;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 20px 20px 2px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 text-align: center;">
<center><h3>Данный e-mail уже зарегистрирован. Если Вы забыли Ваш пароль - воспользуйтесь опцией восстановления пароля<br></h3>
<form action="/#res">
    <button type="submit" id="return">ВОССТАНОВИТЬ ПАРОЛЬ</button>
</form></center></div>';
}
else {

    $password_hash = md5($password.$hash); // Создаём хеш пароля

    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `mail`, `date`) VALUES ('$login', '$password_hash', '$mail', TIMESTAMP(14))"); // Добавляем пользователя в базу данных

    if ($result)    
        $user = '

<div style="width: 370px;
height:180px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 5% auto;
 padding: 20px 20px 2px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 text-align: center;">
<h3>Вы успешно зарегистрированы! <br>Теперь Вы можете войти на сайт как зарегистрированный пользователь.</h3><br>
<a href="#authForm"><input type="button" value="ВОЙТИ НА САЙТ" id="return"/></a></div>';

    else
        $user = '

<div style="width: 370px;
height:140px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 20px 20px 2px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
Данный Логин уже существует! <br>Попробуйте ещё раз или обратитесь к администратору.<br>
<form action="/#regForm">
<input type=button onclick="window.location.reload()" id="return" type="submit" value="ВЕРНУТЬСЯ К РЕГИСТРАЦИИ">
</form></center></div>';

    echo $user;
    }
?>
```

б) Код обработчика js:

```
$(function() {

$("#nosubmitform").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
    var login = $('#regLogin').val();
    var password = $('#regPassword').val();
    var mail = $('#regMail').val();
    if (login == '' || password == '' || mail == '') {

    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url:        '/reg.php',
            type:       'POST',
            cache:      false,
            data:       {'login':login, 'password':password, 'mail':mail},
            dataType:   'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('#regForm').hide();
                $('#regMessages').html(data);
                $('#regMessages').show();
            }
        });
    }
});

});
```

в) В самом index.php файле так же содержится вот что - для вывод этих сообщений.

```
<div id="regMessages" >
</div>
```

РЕЗЮМЕ:

Есть сайт с регистраций. Регистрация проходит успешно. Однако вывод об успешной регистрации в данный момент происходит не через всплывающее окно, как регистрация, а хотелось бы через всплывающее или просто окно с затемнением содержимого сайта. Скорее всего это связано с обработчиком js. Код написан так, что нельзя в echo запихнуть всплывающее окно или просто окно с затемнением содержимого сайта. Или же можно?

Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Вы смотрели Ajax Вам  возвращает данные ?

Comment: функция работает. Код правильный. Но он глупый. Мне кажется надо просто js убрать из кода и все будет.